# Is it possible to select JDK 8 for Java project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code to compile and run a maven-based Java project.

VSCODE requires for itself JDK 11. I installed JDK 11 and added it as java.home in VSCODE "Java: Configure Java Runtime" section.

The project however requires Java 8.
I have JDK 8 pointed by JAVA_HOME, and pom.xml specifies

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

However when I compile and try to run the project in VSCODE, I get messages

```
Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-1.8. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment. 

The compiler compliance specified is 1.8 but a JRE 11 is used.
```

Even though VSCODE knows JDK 8 is reachable:

[image]

How do I instruct VSCODE to use JDK 8 (rather than JDK 11) as runtime for the project?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible as VSCode support projects from Java 1.5 and above although. You need to focus on the runtime configuration. Check the link below.
[Java Runtime VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-jdk)

Meanwhile, I will strongly recommend you use other IDEs like eclipse or Intellij for Java projects for proper debugging, perspectives, maven, gradle, library support, etc

Comment: The plugin says it will correctly respect the maven definition. The documentation is not yet updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.
You show all commands (ctrl+Shift+P) and search for "java: configure java runtime".
[This is the screen you'll get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DQVk.png)

On the left side you can see workspace overview (make sure version 1.8 is available)
On the right side, you can see "Maven/Gradle Projects" click on the drop down menu and you should be able to select the jdk1.8.0.

This should solve your problem. Please let me know if it did!

Comment: "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" v0.82.0 (latest) does not have a "Java: Configure Java Runtime" command.  See https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java